# ConversionException in running a Jmeter jmx file with Ultimate thread group in Intellij maven

Tags: maven, jmeter

Facing the below issue in running Ultimate thread group jmx in intellij  maven (please note, for normal thread group jmx file, there is no issue. And in pom file also the required dependencies are added, which i believe is the ctg(custom thread group) one) . I am getting this error for that jmx  execution alone -

missing class Conversion Exception:
required-type-ListedHashTree
converter-type-ScriptWrapperConverter

What needs to be changed now to make it executable in intellij . I am using mvn commands to trigger the jmx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found the solution to this. Apart from adding it to the dependency,

You need to add this also to the jmeter extensions in the pom.xml

```
                <jmeterExtensions>
                    <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:2.8</artifact>
                </jmeterExtensions>
```

My script started running after this change in pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the following dependency to your project classpath:

[jmeter-plugins-casutg](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-casutg)

Something like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-plugins-casutg</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
</dependency>
```

You may find [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article and [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/src/master/) repository for some examples.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I also checked that first. But it is there in my pom.xml. Actually I wanted this ultimate thread group so that delay between thread groups can be put easily. is there any other way of putting delay between thread groups? I want something like this                 1.Run with 10 users for 5 minutes
2.Wait for 5 minutes
3Run with 20 users for 10 minutes
4.wait for 5 minutes   , if this is achieved also, this can be considered as an answer and will close this.